# Python import function from file1 to file2, cannot access global vars loaded in file2 for function

Tags: python, import, global-variables

**file1**

```
from file3 import helper_func # a function
from file3 import fixed_var # a constant (type string)

def new_func(id):
    url = fixed_var + f'_and_{id}'
    output = helper_func(url)
    return output
```

**file2 attempt1**

```
from file1 import new_func 

new_func('words')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

**file2 attempt2**

```
from file3 import helper_func # a function
from file3 import fixed_var # a constant
from file1 import new_func 

new_func('words')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

The error is thrown both times for the line `url = f'{fixed_var}_{id}'`. `fixed_var` is `None` in both attempt1 and attempt2. Presumably, even if i were to get past this line, the next line would throw an error along the lines of `cannot find function helper_func`.

How can I import `new_func` from **file1** into **file2** and use?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there is a reason not to have this variable as a function parameter?

Comment: If the value of `fixed_var` is determined after a certain function call in `file3` this may happen. The value of `fixed_var` will be `None` until some value is given to it. Also please make sure you have an empty file named `__init__.py` in the directory where all these files are located.

Comment: Are you sure you've shown us all of file1?  f`{fixed_var}_{id}` does not call `+`.  You're sure that there's not some other definition of `new_func` later in that file.   The error message you're showing makes no sense.

Comment: @FrankYellin the original code was `url = fixed_var + f'_{id}'`

Comment: It seems `new_func` did find `fixed_var`, and its value was `None`.  So there is no reason it shouldn't also find `helper_fun`.  The error you're getting clearly indicates that `fixed_var` does have a value, just not the one you're expecting.

Comment: Correct, `fixed_var` is a basic constant string variable being loaded, so it definitely shouldn't be None.

Comment: @unityJarvis what does the `__init__.py` file do here that would help with the issue?

Comment: @FrankYellin I've updated the example code above to accurately reflect the error message. I'm still not sure how to make it so that the value of `fixed_var` is not equal to **None**

Comment: @Canovice - Although Python works without an `__init__.py` file you should still include one.

It specifies that the directory should be treated as a package, so, therefore, include it (even if it is empty). - Read more from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50307979/12950723